# Can't access Body tag of a BasePage in its Codebehind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to add a Javascript to all my pages in the Site. So, I created a base Page and Most of the Pages on the site are inherited from this Page using the `<@Reference` tag. Here's a Sample of my Base Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="BasePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProj.BasePage" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <title></title>
</head>
<body  ID="BasePage_Body" runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In basepage.aspx.cs I am using this as follows..

```
   protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
            {
               base.OnInit(e);
    //Adding this Client Side script for my Page
                if (<someCondition>)
                {
                    BasePage_Body.Attributes.Add("onunload", "HandleClose()");
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "MWGBrowserhandlingClose",
                        "<script language=\"JavaScript\">" +
                        "function HandleClose() {" +
                              "alert(\"Killing the session on the server!!\");" +
                              "PageMethods.AbandonSession();" +
                                "} </script>");
                }
}
```

But I get Nullreference Exception for `BasePage_Body` Any inputs on why is this and how to resolve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using the wrong tool to add JavaScript to all pages in the site. Instead, you should use a [master page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).

Comment: As you can see, I am basically trying o call a PageMethod from Client Side, MasterPages and User Controls doesn't go well with PageMethods...Thats why iam using this kind of approach

Comment: You shouldn't be using PageMethods in the first place, or web methods. Microsoft no longer supports them, and heavily favors [Web API instead](http://www.asp.net/web-api). But an easy fix is to move your logic into web methods in an ASMX or to take the logic and put it in a generic handler ASHX.

Comment: Ohh...I am using WebMethods/PageMethods if I have to communicate something from Client to Server in my Web App. Could you kindly clarify why this isn't a good practice? Also provide me more details about the Handler you are talking about

Comment: You can add a generic handler (.ashx) to your application from Visual Studio's add new item menu. It's just an endpoint where you're handed a raw HTTP Request and you can write to the raw HTTP Response. So it's a very lightweight way to expose an endpoint for AJAX calls. As for web and page methods, those are just dying a slow death. John Saunders have a blog entry [here](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/) describing several reasons why not to use it. He recommends WCF instead, but since then Web API is now available.

Comment: Okay..Here's why I am doing this. I am trying to abandon the session when the user closes his browser(by clicking x on top right of browser not ALT+F4). I am adding this script to call `Session.Abandon()` from the server side. Thus using PageMethods.  How can we simulate this with generic Handlers?

Comment: Just move the logic from the page method into the method of a new generic handler. Then make an AJAX call (perhaps using a library such as jQuery AJAX) to the URL of your ASHX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91138/discussion-between-programmerzzz-and-mason).